# Adding and storing form fields

Tags: joomla, php, forms, quickform

I figured out how to add form fields using the buildForm hook.  I am adding a select element to a participant profile on an event registration form.  Do the values from the added fields get saved when the user submits the form?  If so, where can I see them?  If not, how do I store them with the other profile info using code?  The custom fields feature does not work (DB Error: Already exists)  right now or else I would use that.

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question about fixing your custom fields issue!  There is a lot of capability built in for custom fields that is not there for your own manual fields.

Comment: @Aidan I have just posted a question on how to solve my custom fields issue.  It can be found at [link](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24281/custom-field-set-creation-yields-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary)  Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 2):

[`buildForm`](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook is used to add the elements on the form. To store the values of your select element, you need to look at [`postProcess`](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postProcess/) hook which is called after the form is submitted.

You'll get the submitted select value in `$form` parameter. Use this and store the value in your expected table.

Answer (score 0):

As Jitendra explained you can use the `postProcess` hook and the `$form` parameter. The submitted values will be in an array `$form->_submitValues`.